# Having trouble with SSH localhost

Tags: ssh, localhost

I am trying to connect my UTM virtual machine to my host terminal on mac. I am using ubuntu 22.04.3. My VM has port forwarding set up with guest port 22 and host port 2222.

When I run `ssh benwal@localhost -p 2222` I get no error messages, but it does not prompt me for a password, and it runs without terminating. Here is what I get when I run verbose using `ssh -vvvvv benwal@localhost -p 2222`:

```
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/benwalderman/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/benwalderman/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/benwalderman/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to localhost port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/benwalderman/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/benwalderman/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/benwalderman/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/benwalderman/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/benwalderman/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/benwalderman/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/benwalderman/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/benwalderman/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/benwalderman/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/benwalderman/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/benwalderman/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/benwalderman/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/benwalderman/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/benwalderman/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6
```

Comment: @user68186 I just edited my original post again, I hope this makes things more clear.

Comment: I thought the extra verbosity would give me some clue about whats happening. It does not. It looks like the process hangs. I don't use Macs, but for Ubuntu hosts and guests, using QEMU/KVM, I can use `ssh benwal@IP.address.of.VM -p 2222`, where the `IP.address.of.VM` is the IP address the VM software (QEMU, parallel, VirtualBox, VMWare, etc.) assigns to the Ubuntu VM guest instance.

Comment: The "localhost" refers to the IP address 127.0.0.1. This is a special IP address that points itself (the real computer you are using). Unless your Mac VM software changes this fundamental aspect of the "localhost" it should not point to the VM's gateway IP address. Add the local IP address of your Mac, local IP address of the VM software's local IP address of gateway, and the Guest VM to your question. I want to see which local IP address ranges they belong to.